# Python Subprocess Commands to Update Node Submodule - NVM, NPM, and Node v18.14.1

Tags: python, node.js, git, ubuntu, subprocess

I'm trying to add a code to my python project that will run the following sequence of commands to update a node submodule in my git repo.

```
git submodule update 
nvm use v18.14.1
npm install <node-package>
```

This may seem like it should be straightforward enough, but since nvm is a function and not a shell script in a normal location that ubuntu looks for, it can't be found by python subprocess commands. The python code calling subprocesses is being run as a service, and what I need is to be able to enter a shell environment where I can use the npm version installed in the .nvm folder by the nvm function, and where it can access the right node version when running. When I try a direct path to my npm command, npm can't find node and won't work.

I'm trying to not install npm or node using apt-get because I am using a custom version installed with nvm for this service. When i login as the unprivileged service user using sudo su, I can run the above commands successfully.

How can I run my update commands for the node submodule in this environment as the running service from python?

Is there a way to get these to execute in the right environment? Or is there a way to specify the node binary location to a direct call to an npm command in the .nvm folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this for my project by passing a PATH variable in the env argument of python subprocess calls like this:

```
subprocess.run(['thing'], env={'PATH':'path/to/thing/bin'})
```